# How to convert dynamic js object into single line string?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am facing problem to convert a dynamic object into a single line string. My Object is as follows:

```
var data= {0: "How many colors do you have?", 
1: "How many stock do you have?", 
2: "Do you provide separate price?"
};
```

I need to convert that object into the followings:

```
var message = 'How many colors do you have? How many stock do you have? Do you provide seperate price?';
```

Note: the object is not fixed to that three only, it change dynamically, so it becomes 3, 4, 5 or any other number of data.

Comment: What did you try yourself?  This isn't a particularly difficult problem.  Why didn't you try something yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
var message = "";
for(var i = 0;i < Object.keys(data).length;i++){
   message += data[i]+" ";
}
```

Comment: is it possible with any higher order function?

Comment: This puts an extra space at the end of the string.

Comment: try this : Object.keys(data).map(function (key){return data[key]}).join(' ');

Answer (score 2):

```
var res = Object.keys(data)
  .map(function (key) {
    return data[key];
  })
  .join(' ');
```